# java setToolTipText dependiendo de la cantidad de caracteres ingresados en un jTextField

Tags: java, condiciones, tooltip

Estoy intentando que un tooltip se muestre si cumple una condición y si no se cumple que muestre otro.
Eso lo he logrado. Ahora el tema es así, **deseo que si escriben hasta 5 caracteres**, por ejemplo muestre determinado mensaje, en mi caso **Presione ENTER para crear.**  y para el caso de que **se exceda de 5 caracteres**, muestre el mensaje **Alcanzo la Longitud Maxima 5 caraceteres**, y en ese caso lo que hago es un **evt.consume();** para que no pueda seguir ingresando datos.

*El problema es que queda con este ultimo mensaje el tooltip*, cuando uno borra y si desea corregir, la leyenda del tooltip que se sigue mostrando es la ultima de **Alcanzo la Longitud Máxima 5 caracteres**. Lo que deseo es que si borran o sigue estando en menos de 5 caracteres muestra la leyenda inicial de **Presione ENTER para crear.**.

Dejo una imagen para que entiendan el error:

### [image: Título]

El código:

```
    private void aLongitud(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                           
    if (nombreTextField.getText().trim().length() < 5 || evt.getKeyChar() == java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) {
        final ToolTipManager manager = ToolTipManager.sharedInstance();
        final int oldDelay = manager.getInitialDelay();
        manager.setInitialDelay(0);
        manager.mouseMoved(new MouseEvent(nombreTextField, 0, 0, 0,
                0, 0,
                0, false));
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            manager.setInitialDelay(oldDelay);
        });
    } else if (nombreTextField.getText().trim().length() >= 5) {
        evt.consume();
        nombreTextField.setToolTipText("Alcanzo la Longitud Máxima 5 caracteres");
        final ToolTipManager manager = ToolTipManager.sharedInstance();
        final int oldDelay = manager.getInitialDelay();
        manager.setInitialDelay(0);
        manager.mouseMoved(new MouseEvent(nombreTextField, 0, 0, 0,
                0, 0,
                0, false));
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            manager.setInitialDelay(oldDelay);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: En este caso en particular, solo debes volver a aplicar el tooltip de "*Presione Enter para crear*" dentro del bloque `if`, de ese modo actualizas su estado.

Comment: Hola JonnyTB gracias por responder, he intentado lo que dices pero no me funciona. Sigue quedando el ultimo ToolTip "Alcanzo la Longitud Máxima 5 caracteres"